# USB-C connector's suitability in a moderate- to high-vibration environment

Tags: connector, usb-c, vibration

Garmin has long deployed USB minis in aviation and it has seemed to work out. I'm curious if there is any data out there about USB-C's history in moderate- and high-vibration environments, such as an aircraft. The USB-C connector is good for auto-negotiating power and data, and has a ubiquity which makes it interesting for aviation. But I can't find any data from manufacturers about the vibration standards they design USB to and I'm not keen to discover on my own what other people may already know.

Q: Is there published manufacturer or trade vibration data about USB-C plugs and receptacles?

Comment: I'll bet that vibration was not on the minds of those that came up with the USB-C standard.  Data rate - YES.  Power delivery - YES.  But vibration, shock, NO.

Comment: That's a nice assertion, but do you have any data to back that up? USB had already been ubiquitous for decades before, and so it's entirely possible the committee thought about it being used in hardened environments. Certainly automotive manufacturers would have brought this point up (if they were indeed consulted). In fact, I can't think of why anyone would design a 21st century connector and not at least wonder about vibration resistance. It's one of the premier reason why connections fail.

Comment: So, is that's the case, then what vibration and or shock environment did they design to?  Some Mil standard (airborne fighter, rocket launch & stage separation)?  Some automotive standard?  So if you think they designed to some vibe standard, you should be able to provide that detail.  The onus isn't on me (or anyone else) to prove the negative - that they didn't design to such a standard.

Comment: The existence of these suggests it's probably not vibration resistant enough for all applications https://www.theimagingsource.com/en-us/product/accessory/usb-31-cable/

Comment: @SteveSh I'm confused by your argument. You have asserted you do not believe vibration was a consideration in the design process, and I've asked you to back that up with data. I'm not sure why the onus is not on the asserter to back up the assertion with data.

Comment: @AlanBirtles good link, maybe they have some published data or can provide some use scenarios. I'll call them next week. From the 30k' view, the connector coming free is one way the connection can fail, but the spring-loaded pins can also bounce and chatter inside the body, disrupting the connection. I don't expect the locking screws would address that.

Comment: @Kenn Sebesta - In general when some asserts a positive - like the USB-C connector was designed for a vibration environment - it is up to them to provide proof of that assertion.

Comment: @SteveSh who asserted that? Could you send me the quote?

Comment: You did - "USB had already been ubiquitous for decades before, and so it's entirely possible the committee thought about it being used in hardened environments. Certainly automotive manufacturers would have brought this point up (if they were indeed consulted). In fact, I can't think of why anyone would design a 21st century connector and not at least wonder about vibration resistance."

Comment: The 413 page USB-C cable and connector specification (https://www.usb.org/documents) contains zero mentions of "vibration" or "shock".  Pull-out force and twisting resistance, yes, but not vibration or shock.  Both of these tests are extremely difficult to perform correctly and for USB-C would depend heavily on the cable itself and its actual physical orientation so making one specification would be so hedged with reservations as to be useless. There is no positive record for "we didn't design it to withstand x condition" because that list would be infinitely long.

Comment: @SteveSh uh... that's, um, quite the leap to go from "entirely possible" and "at least wonder" (my words) to "was designed for" (your words). Have you ever done engineering design before? If so, certainly you've considered something and then decided it was outside of scope. Your assertion that is was "not on the minds" is a powerful one and might be right, but you've steadfastly refused to provide any data to support that. This is a good time to either delete those comments or provide some data. Otherwise, we're just wasting everyone's time.

Comment: @vir thanks, that's good data. It shows that the design is silent on vibration (which is expected for all the reasons you state). Now if I could only get an answer to the question, which is whether manufacturers or trade groups have published empirical results. It's easy to find manuf. talking about IP rated USB-C connectors and high lifespan of mating cycles (both also presumably not in the original spec), but I can't find anyone discussing vibration.

Comment: I very much doubt it since the tried and true method would be to use a connector family explicitly designed to withstand vibration such as 38999 where the tests have already been done instead of testing something that was never designed for it in the first place.

Comment: @Kenn Sebesta - 53 years design experience, including many systems critical to our (US) national defense.  How 'bout your background?